# Writing simple LaTeX workspace

Tags: programming, editors

I have this project in which I need to write something like a workspace for LaTeX.

Basically I need to make split window. In one you would write the TeX code and in the other you would see the live result of your doing. And I have to add some other small things like coloring the syntax, changing the compile method (LaTeX, XeLatex...) etc.

I know and I've written some documents in LaTeX, so I know LaTeX fairly.

But!!! Where should I start? I don't know anything about it. Is there maybe some **simple** code to begin with? is there a **small** example? anything?

I'm not lazy. I went through the internet and found very few things about it.

Would like to hear some advice.

Comment: You sound like you are asking about LaTeX editors: there is a [question about these in general](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides). The way you describe the layout you want is available in several editors: I use TeXworks, which has a split 'one side code, one side output' approach, but so do many other editors.

Comment: Although I need to write it myself. So I will use only the latex exe to interpret the code or whatever exe to do so.

Comment: If I get you right then you are trying to program your own simple LaTeX editor. Therefore your question is maybe better placed within a section of sx that is more focussed on programming. For this you should maybe abstract it a bit more and first ask for some code that has an editor component in on half of the window and a second area where the content of the editor window is built by some random compiler. From there you could go on to get more LaTeX specific.

Comment: @Benedikt-Bauer I guess you right. Please can you clarify what is "section of sx"? I would do as advised. Thanks

Comment: @MaD sx is the shorthand for "stackexchange" and for example tex.sx is a section of stackexchange. Maybe it's best to start at the http://stackexchange.com site and see which sections would best fit your needs.

Comment: @MaD In addition to what Benedikt says, I'd note that asking 'How do I write an editor?' is likely to be too broad on StackOverflow. You seem to want an interface with a code editor part and a (PDF?) viewer part: you should ask focussed questions on specific issues you ware facing.

Comment: Also, are you supposed to use a particular programming language?

Comment: I may use C# or C++. For me C# is more friendly

Comment: Certainly questions about C# or C++ are not on-topic for us! If there are specific questions about the LaTeX side of things, I suggest you ask them separately.

Comment: @MaD So I believe StackOverflow.com is the place to ask. Your question is really about `C#` or `C++`, but this is a Q&A about LaTeX... When you ask your question there, make sure you tag the question with `C#` or `C++` so you get help from the right people. This question is probably going to be closed, but I hope you come back here to ask questions should you have LaTeX problems in the future :)

Comment: @Joseph-Wright yes, you completely right. I asked in a programing section about it. Is there anything I need to do about this question? like close or delete? Thanks

Comment: @MaD It has been closed, don't worry. Good luck on SO!